# Error on my eslint when trying to run my vue js app

Tags: vuejs2, eslint

I've just started learning vue but when trying to run the app through vue cli I get the following error

[this is the error from my vue cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsMCC.png)

This is my eslint code

```
    #!/bin/sh
    basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

    case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
    esac

    if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
    "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
    ret=$?
    else
    node  "$basedir/node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js" "$@"
    ret=$?
    fi
    exit $ret
```

Comment: Could you put your code in the question, rather than an image? See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [Creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more info.

Comment: How are you running eslint? `npm run lint`? On what version are your `vue-cli` dependencies?

Comment: why are you eslinting a bash file?